# Not able to include calendar events, sorting table in a single page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, calendar

There are two html files for calendar and sorting table running perfectly on different pages but want to integrate both calendar and sorting table in a single angularjs page.Each html file has seperate app.js and .css.But i want to combine both and show in a single page. Please advice how can i make it?

Thanks, Suni

Comment: You need to show some code samples for anyone to really be able to help you.  What kind of calendar?  Is it Angular ui-date-picker?  What kind of table?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what exactly you mean as there is absolutely no code right now, but I think you may want to use `iframe`. Here is the syntax:

```css
        .iframe1 > iframe {
        width: 49%;
        height: 100vh;
        border: none;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        }

        .iframe2 > iframe {
        width: 49%;
        height: 100vh;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        }
        
            body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="iframe1"><iframe src="https://www.bing.com/"></iframe></div>
  
    <div class="iframe2"><iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"></iframe</div>
```

Hope it helps.